# Moving an image with MouseListener when CLICKED

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am trying to make an image move with the mouse when user the clicks/holds the mouse button down. I have managed to do this when the user HOLDS the mouse down (in which it updates in real time with the mouse), however, when I CLICK on the image, the image adjusts its position to the updated area, which is not what I want it to do. The only time I want the image to move if it is CLICKED is if the user clicks again, for the second time. So lets say if the user clicks on the image, which is located at (0,0), if the user clicks again somewhere else on the screen, then the location is now at (x,y).

Here is what I have:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    clickCount++;
    if(clickCount % 2 == 0){
        p.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());//p is just a panel that contains the img
        repaint();
    }
    System.out.println("mouse clicked...");

}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    Object o = e.getSource();
    if(o instanceof JPanel)
        clickCount++;

    if(clickCount % 2 == 0 && clickCount != 0){
        p.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        repaint();
    }
    System.out.println("mouse clicked " + clickCount + " times");   
}
```

This is closer to working, however, if you click anywhere on the screen (after clickCount % 2 == 0), then the image will move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `mouseClicked` is called, determine if something was previously clicked, if it was, move the object to the current location, if it wasn't, check to see if the user clicked something was movable and assign it to a variable (which you use to check later).

Once the object is moved, set the reference to `null`

```
private JPanel clicked;

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    if (clicked != null) {
        clicked.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        clicked = null;
    } else {
        // Figure out if any panel was clicked and assign
        // a reference to clicked
    }

}
```

## Runnable example...

So, it sounds like you're trying to support both click and drag relocation, this is kind of ... difficult, as the mouse operations required for both are different, so you need to monitor multiple states and make decisions about state you might be in, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MouseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MouseTest();
    }

    public MouseTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(null);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            panel.setSize(50, 50);
            panel.setLocation(50, 50);
            add(panel);

            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
                private Point offset;
                private Point clickPoint;
                private JPanel clickedPanel;

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    // Get the current clickPoint, this is used to determine if the
                    // mouseRelease event was part of a drag operation or not
                    clickPoint = e.getPoint();
                    // Determine if there is currently a selected panel or nor
                    if (clickedPanel != null) {
                        // Move the selected panel to a new location
                        moveSelectedPanelTo(e.getPoint());
                        // Reset all the other stuff we might other was have set eailer
                        offset = null;
                        clickedPanel = null;
                    } else {
                        // Other wise, find which component was clicked
                        findClickedComponent(e.getPoint());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    // Check to see if the current point is equal to the clickedPoint
                    // or not.  If it is, then this is part of a "clicked" operation
                    // meaning that the selected panel should remain "selected", otherwise
                    // it's part of drag operation and should be discarded
                    if (!e.getPoint().equals(clickPoint)) {
                        clickedPanel = null;
                    }
                    clickPoint = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    // Drag the selected component to a new location...
                    if (clickedPanel != null) {
                        moveSelectedPanelTo(e.getPoint());
                    }
                }

                protected void findClickedComponent(Point p) {
                    Component comp = getComponentAt(p);
                    if (comp instanceof JPanel && !comp.equals(TestPane.this)) {
                        clickedPanel = (JPanel) comp;
                        int x = p.x - clickedPanel.getLocation().x;
                        int y = p.y - clickedPanel.getLocation().y;
                        offset = new Point(x, y);
                    }

                }

                private void moveSelectedPanelTo(Point p) {
                    if (clickedPanel != null) {
                        int x = p.x - offset.x;
                        int y = p.y - offset.y;
                        System.out.println(x + "x" + y);
                        clickedPanel.setLocation(x, y);
                    }
                }

            };

            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but why would you set clicked to null? Wont you only be able to enter the IF once then?

Comment: Once you have moved it, you no longer want to continue moving (I assume), so the next click would then select what ever other panel was clicked.  If you want to use dragging, then use a `MouseMotionListener` and the `mouseDragged` event instead

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! :D

Comment: I just have one last question if you dont mind, since I dont want to use this unless I understand everything: why do you do the calculations in findClickedComponent() and moveSelectedPanelTo() for x and y? I know it will give you the correct, updated coords, but I cant seem to understand why.

Comment: Basically, the calculations are taking the original offset point you clicked at, and generating a new offset so that the component doesn't "jump" to the cursor position, so, for example, if you clicked the bottom right corner and dragged the component, the component would remain "anchored" to the bottom right corner, based on the mouse's current position, rather then it jumping down so that the top/left corner was positioned under the mouse

Comment: Ohhhh, I understand it now. I actually paid attention to the spot I clicked on the panel and it is updated exactly as you said. So if I click on the very middle of the panel and I update the position to, say, (10, 50) then the middle of the panel will be at point (10, 50), instead of the top left corner. THANK YOU VERY MUCH AGAIN! :D